# how to reset anchor point after UIView (with UIImageView inside) was scaled?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview, anchor, catransform3d

I want to do catransform3dmakerotation on some UIView that contain UIImageView so that it looks like they are rotating. It works, BUT the anchor point is wrong (no longer at the center of the graphics) after I scaled the UIView (and hence stretched the image in it).

How to reset the anchor point? I mean REALLY reset it. Because I tried this :

```
[self.view viewWithTag:100].layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

And every time the accelerometer value is changed, which is updating pretty much every 0.1 second after rescaling, the image is rotating but no longer centered anymore, it seems to be rotating on its origin (0,0), instead of (0.5,0.5), altho it should be updated in the **accelerometer: didAccelerate:** method. But it didn't work. Here is the rescaling code:

```
UIView* buttView = (UIView*) [self.view viewWithTag:101];
UIImageView* butt = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
butt.frame= CGRectMake(butt.frame.origin.x, butt.frame.origin.x, newSize, newSize);
buttView.frame = butt.frame;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Note that if you change the view transform, you're not supposed to access the frame property (set center and bounds instead).

Answer (score 2):

Before changing the `anchorPoint` you need to remember the old frame and after changing reset it. Like this:

```
CGRect oldFrame = [[self.view viewWithTag:100] frame];
[self.view viewWithTag:100].layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
[[self.view viewWithTag:100] setFrame:oldFrame];
```

Comment: Thanks taskinoor. Will give it a try!!